# Keep node in view

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, physics, game-physics, skphysicsbody

I have a question:

Typically, a node will be removed from the view of its position if it exceeds the device's height.

I'm using gravity so it falls back down into the view. How would I make it so the node doesn't remove itself from the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A node does not remove itself from the view once it goes off screen. It's still there but no longer gets rendered. If it has a physics body, physics calculations are still ongoing despite being off screen.

The only instance a node gets removed is if you remove it from parent.

Comment: Thank you! I now know what I did wrong, and it was something unrelated.